# How can I add other tabs on a form in Dynamics 365 Customer Service Hub?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365, powerapps-modeldriven

Each case form is composed of one or more tabs. By default, the Summary tab shows information about the customer, interactions with the customer, and other related records. You can select different tabs to enter or see other miscellaneous details of a record.

For example, here's a view of how the tabs appear on the case form:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gh5ag.png)

Where should I enable to add other tabs?

Comment: any follow up questions?

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the form by going to [form designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/model-driven-apps/create-and-edit-forms#edit-a-form) and follow [these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/model-driven-apps/add-move-or-delete-tabs-on-form).

[image]

Once form tab is added, sections, fields, subgrids can be added further. You will find everything in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/model-driven-apps/form-designer-overview).